# drawing polygon in canvas jquery html

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

```
var c2 = document.getElementById('c').getContext('2d');
c2.fillStyle = '#f00';
c2.beginPath();
c2.moveTo(200, 20);
c2.lineTo(200, 30);
c2.lineTo(300, 100);
c2.lineTo(400, 90);
c2.closePath();
c2.fill();
```

Found [this](http://jsfiddle.net/yd7Wv/1/) tutorial to draw a polygon in canvas. I don't really understand how it works my condition in making my polygon is the location(north,south,east,west) and the length of the sides.

`For example i want 50px north 50px south 50px east 50px west` 
then it will be square how can i achieve this using this sample code any idea is appreciated
or If you can point me to a better solution for example using jquery i would be happy to try the idea

Comment: NB: Canvas coordinates go positive "down" (or "south")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery won't really help you.  It might make finding the canvas easier (but only slightly)

```
// jQuery :
var c2 = $('c')[0].getContext('2d')

// vanilla javascript (as you have it()
var c2 = document.getElementById('c').getContext('2d');
```

Here is the canvas code to render a 50px square starting at point 10, 10.

```js
var c2 = document.getElementById('my_canvas').getContext('2d');
c2.fillStyle = '#f00';
c2.beginPath();
c2.moveTo(10, 10);
c2.lineTo(10, 60);
c2.lineTo(60, 60);
c2.lineTo(60, 10);
c2.closePath();
c2.fill();
```

```html
<canvas id="my_canvas"></canvas>
```

If you want methods like north, south, east, and west, you could build a Javascript class that knows the current point and does the appropriate math.  You might look into [fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com) which is an object oriented wrapper on the canvas methods.

Comment: idea is geat will try and make it work will post in update if successful

Answer (score 1):

what you pass inside moveto and lineto function is xx and y co ordinates, so if you want to draw a square of 50px width you can draw lines accordingly, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2ubafb9k/) is the fiddle

```
var c2 = document.getElementById('c').getContext('2d');
c2.fillStyle = '#f00';
c2.beginPath();
c2.moveTo(200, 0);
c2.lineTo(200, 50);
c2.lineTo(250, 50);
c2.lineTo(250, 0);
c2.closePath();
c2.fill();
```

you can also create rectangles using rect method in canvas

http://jsfiddle.net/2ubafb9k/1/

```
c2.fillStyle="red";
c2.fillRect(10,10,50,50);
```